# Convert date format in Excel from: Month Date, Year to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, date, format

How do you convert the date format in excel cells from Month Date, Year to yyyy-mm-dd?
Example:

```
Apr 13, 2013 to 2013-04-13
Apr 14, 2013 to 2013-04-14
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If day, month, year can be retrieved

```
=MID(A1,5,2)
=LEFT(A1,3)
=RIGHT(A1,4)
```

Then to have date

```
=DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,2)&"-"&LEFT(A1,3)&"-"&RIGHT(A1,4))
```

And use format cells to get the right format